# Conversion of string to non-const char*

Tags: c++

I have some C+ arrays that I have built as follows:

```
std:array<const char *, 4) test1 = {abc.c_str(), def.c_str(), ghi.c_str()};
```

where `abc`, `def`, `ghi` are `std::string`

I have to pass this array to another function which has the following prototype:
`(int argc, char * argv[])`

How should I modify array so that give `non-const char*` ot me that can be passed to above function. Or should I modify the function to const char*. I am not sure if the function tries to modify char* somewhere since this function code is not mine and not available as well currently.
 But, in any case it would be good to ask how would I pass non-const char* array to the above function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
abc.append(1, 0); // guarantee NUL termination
def.append(1, 0);
ghi.append(1, 0);
std:array<char *, 4> test1 = {abc.data(), def.data(), ghi.data()};
```

or

```
abc.append(1, 0);
def.append(1, 0);
ghi.append(1, 0);
std:array<char *, 4> test1 = {&abc[0], &def[0], &ghi[0]};
```

Comment: + `strdup()`/`free()` in case the prototyped function modifies the strings.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what's the point of `abc.c_str();` etc? What side effects does it have?

Comment: @chris: It ensures that the string content is followed by a NUL byte.

Comment: @Alex: `std::string` is not immutable.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a possibility that the function will modify the string, you should resize the string to the maximum size that the function might use then resize it again on return.

```
abc.resize(max);
DoSomething(&abc[0]);
abc.resize(strlen(&abc[0]));
```

If you know for a fact that the function does *not* modify the string, then the function prototype is lying to you. You can lie back:

```
DoSomething(const_cast<char *>(abc.c_str()));
```

Comment: Scumbag function prototypes. That really is the only justified use for that I know of: making up for other people's mistakes. Good point with resizing the string too.

Comment: a `main`-style function can't increase the length of the strings passed in as arguments, even if it does modify them (it could, for example, use `strtok`)

Comment: @BenVoigt, a `main`-style function wouldn't receive `string`s it would receive `char *`s. I suppose if you know that the string length isn't going to change you could dispense with the pair of `resize`.

Comment: @harper: Did you intend to direct that comment to Mark?

Comment: @BenVoigt, since it's my answer I get notified either way. The comparison to `main` doesn't change my answer.